# How to make it harder for people to download mp3s on my website

Tags: jquery, html, mp3, download

I realise its impossible to totally prevent people downloading the mp3s on my website but I know there are ways to make it *harder*. I mean how can I prevent them from looking at the source code and opening the mp3 links, or using the developer tools to inspect the element and simply seeing the link to the mp3 there?

There are many mp3s (up to hundreds) on the page of which all are very short (like 1 second) so it would not make sense I think to make them streaming.

At the moment I have the mp3s simply playing by ID using jquery.

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var played = $(this).attr("class");
$("audio")[played].play();
});
```

Then in the html its like this so can easily be found and downloaded:

```
<audio class="0" src="sound.mp3"></audio>
```

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

Being as you have a lot of code already in place, you might not like this solution, but this is all I can give you:

Using jPlayer, simply change the css to `display: none`. This will remove the ability to interact with the player. You would have to handle the interactions with it yourself, but it would prevent downloads.

UPDATE:

So your real question is how to hide source code. There are a number of methods out there, but one method of doing it is to totally disable the right clicking on your webpage. This, at the very least, makes it much harder to get at your source code.

To be fair, there is no real way to hide source code. The page obviously still has to make use of the code, so it needs to be in a readable format.

```
<script language="javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
Function disableclick(event)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     alert(status);
     return false;    
   }
}
</script>
```

Or an HTML attribute can handle it:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
...
</body>
```

This should disable the right click on your page.

Another method would be JS encryption, which I have no experience with. [This](http://aesencryption.net/) is a nice site for encryption, but how you handle it is up to you.

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't you still be able to see the mp3s in the source code though? At the moment I'm not using any player, its just playing through jquery.

Comment: I tried Jplayer and its a perfectly fine player but it doesn't solve the issue at all. The mp3 urls are just as visible in the source code as they were without Jplayer. Well in fact its identical. Hiding the player doesn't help since originally I didn't even have a player so there was nothing to hide.

On a side note, I don't think being able to physically see the player would enable you to download the mp3s anyway, you always have to go through the code.

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood your question. You mentioned that you wanted to prevent them from opening mp3 links, so I assumed you had links on the page.

Comment: Ok I see the confusion, the links I was referring to are merely triggers to play the mp3, they don't actually link to the mp3 itself. I'm aware of preventing right clicks but that doesn't prevent opening the source or developer tools through keyboard short cuts. I'll look into some other players. Perhaps the flowplayer used as an audio player would work since it seems to have security in that regard for video. Thanks for your help anyway.